# What is the vulnerability in this C code?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to understand buffer overflow attacks better, this is one of the exercises that came up, that has a buffer overflow vulnerability. I would like to know how one can exploit the vulnerability in this code.
I wasn't sure how to search for it.

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    (void) foo(argv[1]);
    exit(0);
}

int
foo(char *arg)
{
    return bar(arg);
}

int
bar(char *arg)
{
    char lbuf[1024];
    if (strlen(arg) >= 1024)
        return -1;

    memset(lbuf, 0, sizeof(lbuf));
    sprintf(lbuf, "%s", "Welcome: ");
    read(0, lbuf + strlen(lbuf), sizeof(lbuf) - strlen(lbuf) - 1);
    printf(lbuf);
    fflush(stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When creating a [mcve] please don't add line-numbers. It makes it much harder for us if we want to try it out ourselves. And please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `lbuf` has 1024 elements. What happens when you try to put more characters than that as input?

Comment: There is a vulnerability in the program not checking `argc` before accessing `argv[1]` so to exploit just omit any program argument.

Comment: @AJFarmar The input is cut off, as `read` is told to read the appropriate amount of characters (And the nul terminator is written by memset) No vulnerablity

Comment: `strlen` assumes the pointer passed in, is in fact, pointing to a string, what if it's not?

Comment: What is the point of passing `argv[1]` to the function anyway? The string length is checked, and then it is ignored. Was it the intention to write it into `lbuf` before passing to `printf`? If so, there is a vulnerabilty because it could contain format specifiers.

Comment: @ChrisO if it's coming from `argv` it's pointing to a string, unless, as [already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54055462/1541563#comment94945048_54055462), `argc` is not sufficiently large.

Comment: So to summarize, check `argc` before accessing from `argv`, and use `puts()` instead of `printf()` or at least use `printf("%s", lbuf)` when outputting user input. In addition to the comments about pointlessness of passing `argv[1]` down to check and ignore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no buffer-overflow there, at all. But that doesn't mean it's secure.

The problem you are expected to find is this line:

```
printf(lbuf);
```

Whenever you provide a format-string, make sure it is safely under your control and only asks for those arguments you provided. Accessing arguments not provided, or of the wrong type, results in undefined behavior (all kinds of bizarre and potentially dangerous things can happen). Additionally, one can use `%n` to poke some memory, which is more obviously dangerous.
In this case, `lbuf` contains `Welcome:` followed by arbitrary insecure user-input.

In addition, the program unconditionally reads `argv[1]` (assumption `argc > 0`), and further assumes it points to a string (assumption `argc > 1`) when passing it to `strlen()`.

Comment: Some explanation of why it's dangerous would be helpful (e.g. that some format specifiers write memory)

Comment: But it does not answer the OP question. `printf(lbuf)` is easily repairable by `printf"%s", lbuf)`, But he asked about the buffer overflow attack not the printf format string one.

Comment: To make this answer decent you should provide some code which will show the use of this attack, not only to print some useless numbers but which gives the attacker something useful.

Comment: @P__J__ And there is none there, as I wrote.

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense actually. The exact type pf vulnerability wasn't clear originally, it just came up in the context of buffer overflow attacks.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is just an UB without any possible hacks (if we consider only the buffer overflow and will analyze any other possible ones).

Buffer overflow to be used a attacking technique must overwrite some data used later in the program. It may be changing the variables, or placing some code (less common but possible)

an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int CheckPassword(void)
{
    char passwd[5];
    int passwordcorect = 0;

    printf("Enter password:");
    gets(passwd);

    if(!strcmp(passwd, "1234"))
    {
        passwordcorect = 1;
    }
    return passwordcorect;
}

int main()
{
    if(CheckPassword())
    {
        printf("\nSpecial priviledges granted!!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nWrong!!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with mingw. 
[image]

And the result:

[image]
[image]

Why did it happen? Because the buffer has overwritten the passwordcorrect variable. It is system, implementation etc related but hacking is not something abstract or portable :)

Comment: What if the input read by the call to `read` includes for example, `%n`?

Comment: @rici it is not the buffer overflow attack only printf format string one. OP did not ask about any possible attack methods only about the buffer overflow. It is obvious nitpick

Comment: What buffer-overflow?

Comment: It's a vulnerability which results in overwriting memory. The important thing is not what the vulnerability is called, but whether it is exploitable. I think that is consistent with the last statement in your answer, with which I certainly agree.

Comment: @Deduplicator don't you know?